# Sed replace first instance of word in each block of text without leaving bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have some text containing identifiable blocks of text stored in a variable $mytext:

```
start
This is my house and I can see my car from it.
This is my dog and it dislikes squirrels.
end

start
This is my car and I can see my house from it.
This is my dog and it dislikes squirrels.
end
```

I want to replace just the first "my" with "our" in each block from "start" to "end" so that I end up with

```
start
This is our house and I can see my car from it.
This is my dog and it dislikes squirrels.
end

start
This is our car and I can see my house from it.
This is my dog and it dislikes squirrels.
end
```

So what I've got is the following:

`sed -zE "/start/, /end/ s/my/our/1;q" <<< $mytext`

but this will only replace just the first "my" in the first block and ignores the "my" in the second block. I think that this is because it is finding the first "start" and the last "end" and so only doing the replace once.

*Of course the text in $mytext is a much simpler version of what I'm actually trying to do but it is there to illustrate the point.*

How do I replace both first instances of "my" in the two blocks without leaving bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` first replace the `my` string by an unique character.
Next a "normal" `sed` command where you you replace the first unique character after `start`.
And now restore the remaining temp characters with the original value.

```
sed -zE 's/ my /\r/g;s/(start[^\r]*)\r/\1 our /g;s/\r/ my /g' file
```

Comment: Great idea - nice and easy and does the solution. The problem would be if the unique character "\r" were already in the text. I'll go find which unique characters I could use. Perhaps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/control-characters/ might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give `awk` a chance then use:

```bash
awk 'p==1 {p += sub(/my/, "our")} /^start$/ {p=1} /^end$/ {p=0} 1' file

start
This is our house and I can see my car from it.
This is my dog and it dislikes squirrels.
end

start
This is our car and I can see my house from it.
This is my dog and it dislikes squirrels.
end
```

Comment: Now I've got the reason to get out that copy of Dougherty & Robbins book "sed & awk" and read the chapters on awk! Thank you.

Comment: IMO awk is right tool for this because of conditions and stateful string replacement.